# Tanh returning NaN for large input?

Tags: javascript, hyperbolic-function

In my node.js program, I ran this code

```
console.log(Math.tanh(-858.625086043538));
```

and it returned `NaN`. Yet, tanh (hyperbolic tangent) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicTangent.html is defined for all `x`. It should just return `-1`, but its giving `NaN`. Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bad implementation in [Node.js (v5.4.1) version of V8 (4.6.85.31)](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/4.6.85.31/src/math.js#184) which is taking e^(+/-x) which, for an input that larger, results in the return of (`-Infinity / Infinity`) which, further, is `NaN`.

The good news is this was fixed in [V8 version v4.8.87 with a commit that moved to a js fdlibm port](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/47c9e1c904050f82c4e527c5f86fc287856cdd3c). This is why it works in your current-version Chrome DevTools.

If you cannot wait until Node.js pulls in the latest V8, you can port over the [current V8 implementation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/4.10.2/src/third_party/fdlibm/fdlibm.js#886) into your own code (which is based on [this port of fdlibm](https://github.com/rtoy/fdlibm-js/blob/payne-hanek-impl/tanh.js#L36)), which seems to work fine. You just run the risk of any fixes or changes to the *real V8 Math.tanh* that may occur in the future. Here's the V8/fdlibm port:

```
Math.tanh = function (x) {
  x = x * 1;  // Convert to number.
  // x is Infinity or NaN
  if (!Math.abs(x) === Infinity) {
    if (x > 0) return 1;
    if (x < 0) return -1;
    return x;
  }
  var ax = Math.abs(x);
  var z;
  // |x| < 22
  if (ax < 22) {
    var twoM55 = 2.77555756156289135105e-17; // 2^-55, empty lower half
    if (ax < twoM55) {
      // |x| < 2^-55, tanh(small) = small.
      return x;
    }
    if (ax >= 1) {
      // |x| >= 1
      var t = Math.exp(2 * ax);
      z = 1 - 2 / (t + 2);
    } else {
      var t = Math.exp(-2 * ax);
      z = -t / (t + 2);
    }
  } else {
    // |x| > 22, return +/- 1
    z = 1;
  }
  return (x >= 0) ? z : -z;
};
```